# Which statement is true

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Which of the statements is true?

a.) If a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions converges to a function $f$ on $S$, then $f$ is integrable on S.

b.) If a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ on a set $S$, then it converges to $f$ pointwise as well.

c.) If $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ on $S$ and $f$ is not differentiable on $S$, then $f_n$ is not differentiable on $S$ for all $n$.

*I know that:

If $f_n$ is continuous on $S$, then $f$ may not be continuous on $S$.

If $f_n$ is integrable, $f$ may not be integrable on $S$.

If $f_n$ is differentiable, then $f$ may not be differentiable on $S$.*

Comment: For the ones of these which are false, you should be able to make a counterexample rather easily. The ones which are true aren't too difficult to prove. What have you tried?

Comment: I'd classify all three statements as semantically incomplete.

Comment: Integrable by what measure? In what sense does it converge if not pointwise? What kind of set is S?

Comment: There are many, many ways in which a sequence of functions could be said to converge to another function. Which of these definitions of convergence are you using here? The default interpretation (the one that people normally mean when they don't qualify their convergence) is pointwise convergence. But if that is your meaning, then b) is a trivial tautology "$P \implies P$", which makes it nonsensical to ask.